# Event.observe in a loop and variables

Tags: javascript, event-handling, prototypejs

To put things in context, I'm loading a list of items via Ajax, creating a div with main info for each one and want to display details on page when clicking on it. So I have that code in my onSuccess :

```
items = transport.responseText.evalJSON(); // my list of objects that contains all the details I'll need for that page
for (var itemID in items)
{
    newDiv = ... // Creating my div with main infos
    $('myDiv').appendChild(newDiv);

    // More code to make everything look pretty and that works fine

    Event.observe(newDiv, 'click', function() { loadItem(itemID); });
}
```

loadItem is my function that will display all the item details. And my problem is that *itemID* isn't replace by its value when creating the observe event, so it always returns the same ID for all items.

Any idea how I can fix that ? I checked *bind* on prototype doc, that seemed to be made for those cases, but probably didn't get it, since it wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a minimal-impact fix, replace your `Event.observe` line with this:

```
Event.observe(newDiv, 'click', loadItem.curry(itemID));
```

Explanation:

In your original code, the event handler functions you're creating *close over* (have an enduring reference to) the `itemID` variable, and so will use the value of that variable at of when the event handler is *called*, not as of when you assign it to the event. That value will be the last value that `itemID` has in the loop — for all of the handler functions. [More about closures here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

With the minimal-impact revised code, we use Prototype's [`curry`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/curry/) function, which will create a function for you that, when called, will call the underlying function with the arguments you gave `curry`. (The name is [from mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying); Haskell Curry came up with the technique, though there are arguments he wasn't the first to do so.) We could do the same thing ourselves:

```
items = transport.responseText.evalJSON(); // my list of objects that contains all the details I'll need for that page
for (var itemID in items)
{
    newDiv = ... // Creating my div with main infos
    $('myDiv').appendChild(newDiv);

    // More code to make everything look pretty and that works fine

    Event.observe(newDiv, 'click', prepLoadItem(itemID));
}

function prepLoadItem(id) {
    return function() {
        loadItem(id);
    };
}
```

...but because Prototype has a general-purpose function for it, we don't have to.

**Off-topic**: Is `items` an array? If not, ignore this off-topic comment. If so, *don't* use `for..in` to loop through it, or at least, not unless you take some precautions the code above doesn't to do it properly. [Details here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html), but `for..in` is *not* for looping through the indexes of an array; it's for looping through the properties of an object. Array objects may well have properties other than array indexes (and in fact, if you're using Prototype, they do.)